# How to rewrite URL in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like this mecanism:

- when user try to access to *localhost/pro/details/alias* => show this page but with tiny url *localhost/alias*
- when user try to directly access to *localhost/alias* => show this page with same url *localhost/alias*
- when user try to access to *localhost/{controller}/{action}/id => show this page as usual

I tried to modify `startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRewrite(@"([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)", "pro/details/$1", skipRemainingRules: true);

    app.UseRewriter(rewrite);

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

It works only for the second bullet.

What's wrong with my code? And how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Do you want to rewrite or redirect? Using the words "tiny url" and "alias" sort of imply that you want a redirect, not a rewrite (i.e. user requests URL `localhost/alias` and is redirected to URL `localhost/some/real/url`).

Comment: In reality, it's a mix of both (rewrite and redirect). But I didn't find right combinaison :-(

Comment: What do you mean by `this page` in your post? Is it the default view for alias Controller? Did `localhost/pro/details/alias`, `localhost/alias` and `localhost/{controller}/{action}/id` point to the same page for `alias` controller? Is there any page for  `localhost/pro/details/alias`, or you may want to redirect to `localhost/alias` instead of only rewrite the URL

Comment: In fact I have on controller 'pro', and one action 'details'. When I hit /pro/details/{alias}, it works, and it's fine :) ! In this case {alias} can change /pro/details/bob, /pro/details/alice, and so on ...

Comment: But I also would like to hit directly /bob or /alice. But if I use routes.MapRoute, I will be redirected and my final url will be /pro/details/bob. In every case, I want to have as final url /{alias}. How to achieve it please ?

Comment: Sorry, if I haven't been very explicit ! By the way I found solution, I will post it below in new comment :) !

Answer (score 1):

Could you try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting#url-rewrite) approach?

```
 var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
     .AddRewrite(@"(P|p)ro/(D|d)etails/(.*)", "$1", skipRemainingRules: true);
```

Comment: Yes, i tried but URL targeted is localhost/something and I haven't any controler and action for that ... => Not Found page :-(

Comment: please keep in mind you have AddRewrite and AddRedirect in that RewriteOptions object.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve my goal, I did following stuff :

First I modify my startup.cs like :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ProfessionnalAlias",
                template: "{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Professionnals", action = "DetailsAlias" });

        });
```

So I created a new route, **after** *default route* in order to target special action : DetailsAlias (see below)

And I also modify my ProfessionnalsController like :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This action have an Integer parameter and redirect to action with alias
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var professional = await _context.professional 
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.id == id);
        if (professional == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        RedirectResult redirectResult = new RedirectResult("/"+professional.alias);

        return redirectResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This action show detail view from alias parameter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<IActionResult> DetailsAlias(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var professional= await _context.professional.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.alias == id);
        if (professional== null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View("Details", professional);
    }
```

Conclusion :

- If I tried to hit directly /bob => show 'Bob Detail page' with same URL
- If I tried to hit /professional/Details/1 => show 'Bob Detail page' with /bob Url

Thanks for help